# How to check the undelivered messages in Amazon MSK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, aws-msk, amazon-msk

I was going through AWS 's service MSK which is Managed Service for Kafka. I wanted to check how many messages have not been consumed by the consumer after I send them from a producer.

Is the only way to do it via enabling the Monitoring options AWS provides?

Because I tried the general Kafka commands and other Stackoverflow answers related to Kafka, they have not worked for MSK. And why can't we do this? When I hit the --describe option with my zookeeper string in my instnace, there is no LAG column there either.

Comment: _hit the --describe option with my zookeeper string_ - Zookeeper flag is deprecated, please use bootstrap-server. Plus, you may need `command-config` option to add security settings

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62591176/2308683

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute below command from local Kafka/bin directory

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server kafka-bootstrap-ip:9092 --describe --group my-group
```

1. Update kafka-bootstrap-ip with actual kafka cluster ip address.
2. Update my-group with actual group name

Comment: Any other way to check the messages inside the MSK? So what is the LAG actually here?

Comment: This command give you the LAG,  you may want to refer the documentaion https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_consumer_lag                 And this doesnt matter if kafka hosted by AWS(MSK) or on premises deployment. This can be use in both the cases.

Comment: you can also use AWS Cloudwatch that may give you more user friendly. This require some additional configuration https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/metrics-details.html ,   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/cloudwatch-metrics.html